# How to transform types of boost::fusion::vector?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I need to define two types for specified typelist: first is `boost::fusion::vector` of these types and second is `boost::fusion::vector` where references and `const` are removed for each type in type list.

For example, I have `int`, `unsigned &` and `long const &`. I need to define `boost::fusion::vector<int, unsigned &, long const &>` and `boost::fusion::vector<int, unsigned, long>`.

Here is my code:

```
struct RemoveRef
{
    template <class T>
    struct apply
    {
        using type =
            typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
    };
};

template <typename...Args>
struct BasicDefinition
{
    typedef typename boost::mpl::vector<Args...> Types;
    typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<Types>::type ArgsType;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::transform<Types, RemoveRef>::type ValueTypes;
    typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<ValueTypes>::type ArgValuesType;
};
```

It works. I get these types as `BasicDefinition<>::ArgsType` and `BasicDefinition<>::ArgValuesType`. But I want to get rid of `boost::mpl::vector`s and build second type directly from the first one. Is it possible to achieve such result?

Something like:

```
template <typename...Args>
struct BasicDefinition
{
    typedef typename boost::fusion::vector<Args...> ArgsType;
    typedef ?????<ArgsTypes, RemoveRef>::type ArgValuesType;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `std::decay_t`

```
template <typename...Args>
struct BasicDefinition
{
    using ArgsType = boost::fusion::vector<Args...>;
    using ArgValuesType = boost::fusion::vector<std::decay_t<Args>...>;
};
```